# Is there a gnote lens for unity available?

Tags: lenses, gnote

Is anybody aware of a unity lens for gnote? Or does anybody know how to tweak the existing unity-lens-tomboy to scan the gnote folder instead of the tomboy folder?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for Gnote-lens, you can place Gnote icon on the system tray at the right-top of your desktop and use it the way you use Tomboy by following the trick from this site:

http://www.irrational.net/2012/04/27/moving-from-tomboy-to-gnote/

I tried that, and happy to use it.